# php loop, func_get_arg(0)

Tags: php, function, indexing, func

can somone explain me how this code works

```
<?php
function append($initial)
{
    $result=func_get_arg(0);
    foreach(func_get_arg()as $key=>value){
        if($key>=1)
        {
            $result .=' '.$value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
    echo append('Alex,'James','Garrett');
?>
```

why do we have a `0` at the `func_get_arg(0)`, and this is a loop there are `0,1,2` shouldn't it only post Alex, James?
and what is the (as) does the `func_get_arg() as $key => value`. give the array the names to the value ?

this is basic but a bit messy!

Comment: The code first extract the first argmuent to a new string, then iterates over all arguments (foreach), but skips the first (if key >= 1). It appends the remaining arguments together with a leading space to the new string...

edit: Uhm, just seeing it - func_get_arg() without parameter should raise an warning or error

Comment: You can read about the `foreach()` syntax in PHP's manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: You wrote it (or you copied from a how not to do it tutorial), you should know what it does.

Comment: I think the `func_get_arg()` in your `foreach` is incorrect as it expects a parameter. I think you intend to use `func_get_args()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it works:

```
<?php
function append($initial)
{
    // Get the first argument - func_get_arg gets any argument of the function
    $result=func_get_arg(0);

    // Get the remaining arguments and concat them in a string
    foreach(func_get_args() as $key=>value) {
        // Ignore the first (0) argument, that is already in the string
        if($key>=1)
        {
            $result .=' '.$value;
        }
    }
// Return it
return $result;
}

// Call the function
echo append('Alex,'James','Garrett');
?>
```

This function will do the same that:

```
echo implode(' ', array('Alex', 'James', 'Garrett'));
```

Comment: change the `func_get_arg()` to `func_get_args()` in the `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

before you used the foreach{} loop. You have returned 'Alex' which is at position 0.

```
$result=func_get_arg(0);
foreach(){

}
return $result; //It returns Alex

//foreach() loop
foreach(func_get_arg()as $key=>value){ 
/*Its looping and only printing after 
the key gets to 1 and then the loop goes to 2.Eg: $result[$key]=> $value; */
if($key>=1)
{
$result .=' '.$value;
}
}
```

Comment: No problem. Yea it can be a rough start sometimes. Some of the moderators here are what they think is "hardcore" and will down vote or close your answers/questions if it not properly explained. But welcome to SO. Its addicting.

Comment: AW.... Okay! Thanks ! .. You've been so helpful. Hope to get more help from you. :D .. Thanks a bunch.